# Error in CAML Query with multiple "AND"

Tags: caml-query, caml

When I run the following query I get an error:

```
<Where>
   <And>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name="IssueLOB" LookupId="TRUE" />
         <Value Type="Lookup">1</Value>
      </Eq>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name="IssueBucket" LookupId="TRUE" />
         <Value Type="Lookup">1</Value>
      </Eq>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name="IssueStatus" LookupId="TRUE" />
         <Value Type="Lookup">1</Value>
      </Eq>
  </And>
</Where>
```

However, when I run the following query(minus one of the Eq statements) everything works fine:

```
<Where>
   <And>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name="IssueLOB" LookupId="TRUE" />
         <Value Type="Lookup">1</Value>
      </Eq>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name="IssueBucket" LookupId="TRUE" />
         <Value Type="Lookup">1</Value>
      </Eq>
   </And>
</Where>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<Where>
<And>
<Eq><FieldRef Name="IssueLOB" LookupId="TRUE" /><Value Type="Lookup">1</Value></Eq>
<And>
<Eq><FieldRef Name="IssueBucket" LookupId="TRUE" /><Value Type="Lookup">1</Value></Eq>
<Eq><FieldRef Name="IssueStatus" LookupId="TRUE" /><Value Type="Lookup">1</Value></Eq>
</And>
</And>
</Where>
```

This should work!

You should use some CAML Query Builder like [U2U Caml Query Builder](http://www.u2u.be/Tools/wincamlquerybuilder/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx), there are many other available!

Comment: Thanks for this Arsalan. I actually came to the same conclusion minutes after I posted this query. Thanks very much.

Comment: No problem! Here to help ;)

Comment: +1, you did it moments before I was to post the same reply ;)

Comment: @FalakMahmood, you have to be quick next time :P

Answer (score 3):

FYI: In CAML each And (or ) conditional agregates can contain only a max of two filters. In order to have more than two you have to concatenate them as @arsalan-adam-khatri demonstrated.

Comment: this saved my life!