# How to query with 3 Conditions? CAML QUERY

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, caml-query, asp.net

I have the first query:

```
  queryMuaj.Query = "<OrderBy>" +
                          "<FieldRef Name ='testb' Ascending = 'TRUE'/>" +
                    "</OrderBy>" +
                    "<Where>" +
                    "<And>" +
                          "<Geq>" +
                           "<FieldRef Name='testb' />" +
                              "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + startDateFx + "</Value>" +
                          "</Geq>" +
                          "<Leq>" +
                              "<FieldRef Name='testb' />" +
                              "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + endDatFx + "</Value>" +
                          "</Leq> " +
                    "</And>" +
                    "</Where>";
```

And I have the second qyery:

```
    query.Query = @"<Where><Eq>
                     <FieldRef Name='Team' />
                     <Value Type='Text'>" + selvalcomp+ @"</Value>
                  </Eq></Where>"
```

And I want to merge the 2 queries into a single query how can I do this? HELP ME PLEASE

Thanks.

Comment: See this very related question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52270/error-in-caml-query-with-multiple-and/52315#52315 (this question has been asked and answered a lot of time before here)

Comment: I would highly recommend getting a tool like the BIWUG Caml Designer http://www.biwug.be/resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
queryMuaj.Query = "<OrderBy>" +
                          "<FieldRef Name ='testb' Ascending = 'TRUE'/>" +
                    "</OrderBy>" +
                    "<Where>" +
                    "<And>"+    
                       "<And>" +
                            "<Geq>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='testb' />" +
                               "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + startDateFx + "</Value>" +
                            "</Geq>" +
                            "<Leq>" +
                               "<FieldRef Name='testb' />" +
                                "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + endDatFx + "</Value>" +
                            "</Leq> " +
                      "</And>" +
                      "<Eq>"+
                         "<FieldRef Name='Team' />"+
                         "<Value Type='Text'>" + selvalcomp+ "</Value>" +
                     "</Eq>"+
                   "</And>"+    
                   "</Where>";
```

Check [my answer on how to write nested query](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184588/sharepoint-context-and-caml-query-is-not-working/184596)

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
<OrderBy> <FieldRef Name ='testb' Ascending = 'TRUE'/> </OrderBy>
    <Where>
    <And>
    <Eq><FieldRef Name='Team' /><Value Type='Text'>" + selvalcomp+ "</Value></Eq>
    <And>
    <Geq><FieldRef Name='testb' /><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + startDateFx + "</Value></Geq>
    <Leq><FieldRef Name='testb' /><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + endDatFx + "</Value></Leq></And>
    </And>
    </Where>
```

Get some reference from this [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/56815/how-to-write-caml-query-with-more-than-3-and-condition) about nest conditions in CAML query.

Comment: in my list for team I have a dropdown menu and it shows me nothing why?

Comment: Please ask a new question or describe your problem properly in question for better understand.